# XNA inheritance issues

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

Basically here is a simplified version of my problem

```
public class A()
{
    public int getNum()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class B() : A()
{
    public int getNum()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}

A test = new B();
test.getNum();
```

I would like the test.getNum() to return twelve but instead the entire getNum function in B is underlined in green. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into inheritance and [`virtual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int getNum()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override int getNum()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you for the quick response. I did not know I had to use "virtual" since I'm used to java.

Comment: Just a quick sidenote: Virtual is when you intend to have a default method, but allow it to be overwritten. Abstract is when you'd require all inheriting methods to override this. You may also declare properties (and possibly methods) as 'new': public new Vector3 Position. The difference between this and a virtual, I'm not actually certain of, although I'd guess that if you'd be refering to it, using its inheriting parent (A in your example), it would also retrieve A's Position

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard yes "new" is a shadow version of the method. if you have an A reference, you'd get A's version of the method, and if you have a B reference, you'd get B's version of the method. with a virtual method, (`virtual` or `abstract`), you get the version of the method linked with the actual object, irrespective of the reference used.

Comment: While it no doubt seems useful, imo I imagine you have to think a lot harder every time you write code... xP I think I'll just sritick to abstract and virtual ^^